# Revolution Slider show slide only on first visit

Tags: wordpress, redirect, revolution-slider, recurring

is there an option in slider revolution that it shows me the frist slide only at the first visit?
Was looking for it everywhere, but couldn't find it...

My Plan is, that a first visitor gets to see slide 1 and 2 and after coming back, only slide 2.
The Slider Site is my Home.

So if that is not possible.
How do i redirect a recurring user to another side?
Tried it with:

```
$redirect_url = home_url('/business/');
if ($_COOKIE['returningUser'] == '') {
    setcookie('returningUser','1');
    wp_redirect($redirect_url);
```

But that didn't work...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You’ve selected Hero Scene as a Slider Type. That allows for 1 slide only. See

http://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/slider-setup/#slidertype for more details.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes I took the Hero one.
After the first slide is done, it switches to slide 2. That works. But I don't want slide 1 to show up on next visit.